# Next button skips Date Picker field and only focuses on EditText

Tags: android, form-fields

I have a form containing some editTexts and datePiker. filling the form when i press next, it focuses on next editText but when ever there is date picker or spinner between the editText, they are skipped and the next editText after them is set focus on. Can somebody please help me with this problem?

Comment: to set focus to particular view set `android:nextFocusForward="@+id/view_you_want_to_have_focus"` to your view in xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
editTextBefore.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            hideKeyboard();
            textView.clearFocus();
            spinner.requestFocus();
            spinner.performClick();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

> OR

Add this line to get focus on spinner

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner); 
spinner.setFocusable(true); 
spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
spinner.requestFocus();
```

You will also need to hide keyboard you can do this using the following method

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use the focusable attribute for your date picker / spinner:

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method to set focus in your attribute

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etText1"  or android:nextFocusForward="@+id/etText1"
```

and

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```